# working with matrix and save everything in one txt file

Tags: python, numpy

I am a real beginner using python 3

I need to subtract two different matrix in a series of txt file and get all the result in just one txt file. the code works until I ask to print (and it does it) but then I keep getting error message when I want to save "ncol= X.shape[1] indecerror: tuple index out of range"

here is the code

```
import sys, os

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

newpath = "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/.../output/differenza"

os.makedirs(newpath)

for txt in range(162, 167):

    #fn = "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/.../output" + str(txt).zfill(0) + ".txt"

    v1 = np.loadtxt("C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/.../output/result_628.txt")

    v2 = np.loadtxt("C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/.../output/result_" + str(txt).zfill(1) + ".txt")

    v3 = v1 - v2

    picture = np.sum(v3)

    print("picture", picture)

    outfn = newpath + "/result_" + str(txt) + ".txt"

    np.savetxt("outfn", picture, fmt='%1.3f')
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with:

```
import sys, os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

newpath = "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/.../output/differenza"

os.makedirs(newpath)

final = np.array()

for txt in range(162, 167):

    #fn = "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/.../output" + str(txt).zfill(0) + ".txt"

    v1 = np.loadtxt("C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/.../output/result_628.txt")

    v2 = np.loadtxt("C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/.../output/result_" + str(txt).zfill(1) + ".txt")

    v3 = v1 - v2

    picture = np.sum(v3)

    print("picture", picture)
    np.append(final, picture)


np.savetxt("outfn.txt", final, fmt='%1.3f')
```

Comment: thanks! just one thing..I actually would like to save all my scalar value in just one file..sorry I think I made a mess trying to explain what I was looking for

Comment: sorry, it might be me but the final= np.array() it is not defined ??

Answer (score 0):

Your v3 is probably just a scalar value (as returned by numpy.sum()) and numpy.savetxt() expects an array_like object.

You could do `np.savetxt("outfn", [picture,], fmt='%1.3f')` or what zipa suggested. But are you sure you want to write multiple files with just a single scalar value?

PS: I would have put this into a comment, but I am not allowed yet :(

Comment: no, actually I wanted them all in one file..but now I am getting different files...xD

Comment: then simply create a list `results=[]` and append to it instead of writing the file with `results.append(picture)`. Then after the loop you can do `numpy.savetxt(filename, results)`.

Comment: sorry but it keeps saving the data in different files :(

Comment: hard to tell why, without seeing your code. did you try zipas code yet? it is basically the same what I suggested.

Comment: it doesnt work..i have problem with the final = np.array()  :\

Comment: try `final = np.array(())` before the loop
and I think it has to be `final = np.append(final, picture)` at the end of the loop

Comment: great, then please consider upvoting ;)